# Module is flat over localization

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization, flatness

Let $S \subset R$ be a multiplicative set, and $M$ is an $S^{-1}R$ module. Then I read on [stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HT) that

> $M$ is flat $R$-module iff $M$ is flat $S^{-1}R$ module.

I see one direction. If $M$ is flat over $S^{-1}R$ then it is so over $R$. This is because localization  $R \rightarrow S^{-1}R$ is flat. Hence so is composite $R \rightarrow S^{-1}R \rightarrow M$.

I don't see the other direction... Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want a hint, you could look at Exercise 2.20 in Atiyah-MacDonald.

Comment: Hint. $S^{-1}M=M$.

Comment: Ah, that seems right. I was a bit skeptic about this because i could argue by UP but not construct an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: If you have found a convincing argument, why not answer your own question and accept it? This will remove it from the unanswered queue, and it will benefit others with the same question to see how you've resolved the issue.

Comment: Right, I'll add this in soon!